# How to create + fill a container in-place?

Tags: c++, in-place

I'm trying to create an array of classes that can't be copied or moved. So I need to create the objects in-place and I can't figure out how to do that:

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
  Foo(int) { }
  Foo(const Foo &) = delete;
  Foo & operator =(const Foo &) = delete;
  Foo(Foo &&) = delete;
  Foo & operator =(Foo &&) = delete;
};

struct Bla {
  Bla(const std::vector<int> & args) {
    for (auto i : args) {
      foo.emplace_back(i);
    }
  }
  std::vector<Foo> foo;
};
```

The compiler complains about the deleted move constructor because it's not guaranteed that all objects are constructed in-place and never moved. I don't have to use `std::vector` as container, so feel free to suggest something else.

Comment: if the vector resizes it has to move or copy elements. Does it work when you first reserve enough space for all elements? What is the exact compiler error?

Comment: `void Bla(const std::vector<int> & args)` -> `Bla(const std::vector<int> & args) : foo (args.begin (), args.end ()) {}`?

Comment: well, my suggestion to reserve wont help of course. would be cool to have a `emplace_no_reserve_more` that is guaranteed to not do any reallocations and  throws when the capacity is smaller than the new size

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius You should elevate you comment to an answer if it is one

Comment: @Lorand Code snippets are not complete answers, in my opinion. If I had an explanation for why one code snippet works, while other doesn't, I would have written an answer.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i guess the reason it works is that the constructor knows the size in advance and can first reserve and construct the elements in place, thus no reallocations are required and no elements need to be moved, though thats just a guess, still not enough for an answer

Comment: I believe `std::deque` works for non-movable non-copyable types and has a similar interface. And you can still `push`, `emplace` and `pop` at the ends.

Comment: @user463035818 My first thought was similar, but only the generic `begin`, and `end` iterators are passed here, without the size information.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `std::distance(begin,end)`

Comment: @user463035818 But wouldn't that, in the general case, iterate over all the iterators in the range? I, somehow, refuse to believe that `std::vector` would iterate over the elements twice, when constructing itself.. That would be significant performance impact given large containers. But it may be.. I am too lazy to look at specific implementations, to see what, exactly is done in those cases, however :/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius What if Foo takes an additional argument that's the same for all objects? `Foo(args[i], extra)`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius not sure in general, but vectors memory is contiguous so I would be very surprised if `std::distance(begin,end)` would do anything else than a simple pointer arithemtic in this case to get the distance

Comment: @user463035818 For a std::vector / random access iterator the distance between begin and end is just pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow that what i just wrote, did you want to address your comment to someone else?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow In that case, my proposed snippet wouldn't work, since it works because there exists implicit conversion constructor from `int`, to `Foo`. There can be no conversion constructors from multiple types.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `std::distance` is a required to have a constant complexity for (legacy) random access iterator.

Comment: @user463035818 For vector iterators, yes, since they are Random Access Iterators. But, I fail to see the general constructors/functions accepting specific iterator type, so it's interesting, to me, how can one detect the actual iterator type, or is it hidden behind STL template magic, that can't be seen by looking at the docs?

Comment: @Holt Oh, that explains it. Thank you :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius To be more precise, `emplace_back` requires `T` to be `Cpp17MoveInsertable` for `std::vector` (only sequence container to require this), while the "range"-constructor require `Cpp17MoveInsertable` only if the iterators does not meet `Cpp17ForwardIterator` (for `std::vector`). You can find details here: http://www.eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts

Comment: So if the args aren't an std::vector (ForwardIterator) the solution would fail because it would still need MoveInsertable.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Most (all?) containers' iterators are `ForwardIterator`, so it would work with `list`, `set`, and so on.

Comment: For the most generic case isn't there some way to make an initializer list from the vector `args` and a lambda?

Comment: @Holt Yeah, I tried a number of container including things like `map` and they all worked. So maybe it is all containers or at least close too it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::vector`s iterator pair constructor to construct the objects like

```
Bla(const std::vector<int> & args) 
    : foo(args.begin(), args.end())
{}
```

If you have additional parameters that you need to include in the construction then you can switch to any of the node based containers like `std::list`

```
struct Bla {
  Bla(const std::vector<int> & args) {
    for (auto i : args) {
      foo.emplace_back(i, some_other_argument);
    }
  }
  std::list<Foo> foo;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. The tip about using a node based container solves it for me. The first (iterator pair constructor) relies on the implicit conversion constructor from `int` to `Foo`, which only works in the simplified code in the question. std::list will work for my use case.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow No problem. If you do need random access you can get the first example to work, it will just require a lot of plumbing and you would have to change `Foo`'s constructor to take a single container of all the parameters instead of each parameter separately.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow if you are fine with a list then maybe you are also ok with a vector of smartpointers

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the range constructor. It doesn't reallocate the vector when random access iterators are passed:

```
Bla(const std::vector<int> & args) 
    : foo(args.begin(), args.end())
{}
```

Comment: Sorry, simplified my question too much. So the answere isn't generic enough. What if Foo takes an additional argument that's the same for all objects like Foo(args[i], extra) for example?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think you should add new question for that. This answer answers the original question i.m.o.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow In this case you would need your class to be movable and use an iterator adaptor.

Answer (score 1):

> For the most generic case isn't there some way to make an initializer list from the vector args and a lambda?

An alternative way to create a STL container of `Foo` that can't be copied or moved is containing `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` which is movable.
For instance, as more generic case, if the first and second arguments of the ctor of `Foo` are `int` and `double` respectively, then the following `Bla` works for you:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ixxh5HngbFSw2JEF)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Bla
{
    Bla(const std::vector<std::tuple<int, double>>& args)
    {
        foo.reserve(args.size());

        for (const auto& i : args) {
            foo.push_back(
                std::make_unique<Foo>(std::get<0>(i), std::get<1>(i)));
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foo;
};
```